# How to detect overflow with text-indent and absolute position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

I have faced with problem. 
I have following html layout

```
<div class="accordion-list-item__controls is-opened">
    <span class="accordion-list-item__toggle-icon fa"></span>
    <span class="accordion-list-item__icon fa fa-mobile-phone"></span>
    <a class="accordion-list-item__link" href="http://crosp.net/category/software-development/mobile/" title="View all posts in Mobile Development">Mobile Development</a>
    <div class="accordion-list-item__post-count">7</div>
</div>
```

And css

```
.accordion-list-item {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
   }
    .accordion-list-item__icon {
      font-size: 1.125em;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 0.27778em;
      text-indent: 0; }
    .accordion-list-item__toggle-icon {
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0; }
      .accordion-list-item__toggle-icon::before {
        display: inline-block;
        content: "";
        color: transparent;
        text-indent: 0;
        font-family: "FontAwesome"; }
    .accordion-list-item__link {
      text-indent: 0;
      margin-left: 0.4375em;
      display: inline-block;
      white-space: initial;
      max-width: 70%;
      vertical-align: middle;
      color: #797e83; }
      .accordion-list-item__link:visited, .accordion-list-item__link:link {
        color: #797e83; }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
        .accordion-list-item__link {
          max-width: 60%; } }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .accordion-list-item__link {
          max-width: 80%; } }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .accordion-list-item__link {
          max-width: 60%; } }
    .accordion-list-item__post-count {
      text-indent: 0;
      font-size: 0.8125em;
      position: absolute;
      display: inline-block;
      right: 0;
      color: #797e83;
      padding: 0 0.61538em;
      margin-right: 0.61538em;
      border: 1px solid #68c3a3;
      border-radius: 10px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s;
      transition: all 0.5s; }
    .accordion-list-item__controls {
      padding: 0.625em 0.3125em;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: block;
      color: #797e83; }
      .accordion-list-item__controls:hover {
        color: #68c3a3; }
        .accordion-list-item__controls:hover .accordion-list-item__link {
          color: #68c3a3; }
        .accordion-list-item__controls:hover .accordion-list-item__post-count {
          color: #f7f7f7;
          background-color: #68c3a3; }
        .accordion-list-item__controls:hover::after {
          border-color: #68c3a3; }
      .accordion-list-item__controls::after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s;
        transition: all 0.5s; }
    .accordion-list-item.is-active > .accordion-list-item__controls::after {
      border-color: #68c3a3; }
    .accordion-list-item.has-children > .accordion-list-item__controls .accordion-list-item__toggle-icon::before {
      content: "";
      color: #797e83; }
    .accordion-list-item.has-children > .accordion-list-item__controls.is-opened .accordion-list-item__toggle-icon::before {
      content: "";
      color: #68c3a3; }
```

The problem is that `accordion-list-item__post-count` is positioned absolutely and I get following result on some screens

[image]

As you can see I tried to set text max width, but because of `text-indent` (padding of nested items is done using text-indent dynamically generated) I cannot set consistent property (max width).

I am looking for any type of solution, even using `JS`/`jQuery`.

But for sure, `CSS` solution is much valuable.

Please share your ideas how to solve this problem.
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: have you considered adding a padding right so you have room for the counters?

Comment: Just like @madalinivascu, the first thing that came to mind to solve this is to add a padding right and word break. [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/qa7pkmea/). However, putting more thought into it, you can also change your design and move the counters to the left.

Comment: try position:relative instead of absolute

Comment: Sorry, I haven't mentioned, I have already tried padding, but padding also doesn't work with different level. 
I will try to generate padding dynamically and share results